# Disable copy on jquery mobile button over PhoneGap

Tags: button, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm developing an app over PhoneGap for an iPhone using jQuery Mobile. When I press (and keep) a button I have this menu (see image below):

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/855/imagexj.png/

How can I disable it?

Thanks in advance,
DGM.-

Comment: Please rewrite your question. It is a little confusing. Try adding screenshots perhaps.

Comment: Thanks. I hope this will be better. @codaniel

Comment: So do you want to disable that button at the top after you click it?

Comment: Nop, I want to disable the menu wich appears (the one with Open and Copy). @codaniel

Comment: Also what version of JQM are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.7.2. So, ok, I can use that over buttons and input, but then how I make them to behave as <a> to make transitions? @codaniel

Comment: Use `$.mobile.changePage( "about/us.html", { transition: "slideup"} );` more about that method @ http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.2/docs/api/methods.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just add the following css code to disable:

> * {
>
> -webkit-touch-callout: none;
>
> -webkit-user-select: none;
>
> }

and only enable something you like:

> input {
>
> -webkit-user-select: auto;
>
> }

Comment: [Reference - Mobile Web & PhoneGap HTML Dev Tips](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/01/17/mobile-web-phonegap-html-dev-tips/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#openBtn').click(function(){
    $(this).button('disable');
});
```

It looks like you can also add the class ui-disabled to a button. You can also simply add the attribute disabled to a button or input tag. Note that this will not work on an `<a>` tag that uses the data-role="button". For some reason it only works on `<button disabled></button>` and `<input type="text" disabled />`