# Why copy paste option come when we tap the the button for 5 seconds?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Can you please tell me why copy, paste option appears after tapping the button for 5 seconds in jQuery mobile? Actually I am using jQuery mobile When I Add button and tap on that it show copy paste select all options?

[image]

```
   <div class="ui-grid-c">
      <div class="ui-block-a"  style="width: 30%;" >
        <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text" autocorrect="off" class="searchbox">     
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false"  data-inline="true"  class="search">Search</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-c" style="margin-left: 5px;">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false"  data-inline="true"  id="next" class="searchNext" disabled>Next</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-d" style="margin-left: 30px;">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" data-inline="true" id="prev"  class="searchPrev" disabled>Previous</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post some code ? maybe a jfiddle ?

Comment: I think it's a browser default action, not JQM's.

Comment: Actually I am testing on Ipad ..!! Here is my update code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Take a look On this link
[Apache Cordova: remove tap-hold link menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753782/apache-cordova-remove-tap-hold-link-menu)

[Disable copy on jquery mobile button over PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126468/disable-copy-on-jquery-mobile-button-over-phonegap)

Use This

```
* {

-webkit-touch-callout: none;

-webkit-user-select: none;

}
```

and only enable something you like:

```
input {

-webkit-user-select: auto;

}
```