# How to remove > sign from list in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

can you please tell me how to remove this > sign from the list in jquery mobile? I inspected in which class that > image is inserted, but unable to find.
http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/MneT6/6/

```
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) { 
  $('#folderData').append(
      '<li class="caseRowClick" id="' + i + '" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">' + '<a href="#">' + '<img src="img/Blue-Folder.png">' + 
      '<h2>' + i  + '</h2>' + '<p>' + i+ '</p>' + '<p>' + i + '</p>' +'<span class="ui-li-count">' + i + '</span>'+  '</a>' +
      '<span class="ctrl togg"><fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true" >' +
      '<button class="edit button_design">Edit</button><button class="del button_design">Delete</button></fieldset><span>' + '</li>'
  );
  $('#folderData').listview('refresh');
}
```

Comment: Solve the problem ..!!

Comment: can you please help me in this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923628/why-copy-paste-option-come-when-we-tap-the-the-button-for-5-seconds